# Does serverless.template support yaml in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-toolkit

I created a aws lambda .net core project with the provided templates

I has a json file `serverless.template` which is in json. SAM templates can be in yaml now and I prefer that because it is readable and can have comments.

When I change serverless.template to be yaml visual studio can no longer read it. Is this supported and is there a config to fix it?

Comment: you managed to find an answer?

Comment: I think the answer is big middle finger to yaml support. vscode has official support for the aws toolkit. If anyone reading this has tried it could they confirm if vscode supports yaml?

Comment: No question that VS Code supports yaml... Not only that but Notepad++ and some other editors can change the line returns, causing a problem. VS Code will not do that. I stick with VS Code for yaml.